# ./bin/rails css:install:bootstrap fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`./bin/rails css:install:bootstrap` is failing.

```
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `assets' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000000010afa4118 @root=#<Pathname:~/Documents/rails_project>
```

What is going on.

I've had trouble running commands like this with spaces in the path, but I don't have spaces in this case.

Comment: Try to find this method with `grep -r assets`

Comment: Thanks but TMI for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.assets` comes from asset pipeline:

`sprockets-rails`
*https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/v3.4.2/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb#L99*

or `propshaft`
*https://github.com/rails/propshaft/blob/v0.6.4/lib/propshaft/railtie.rb#L6*

There was *config.assets* in rails itself, but it was [removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5172d9335931559332125d8f50b75d74af295a15) in *rails 5*.

In *rails 6* and before, `sprockets-rails` was a [dependency](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.7/rails.gemspec#L46) so you would get *config.assets* automatically.

In *rails 7* `sprockets-rails` became [optional](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43261) and you must have `gem "sprockets-rails"` or `gem "propshaft"` in your *Gemfile*.

---

*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#sprockets-is-now-an-optional-dependency*

Comment: Thank you. I'm flailing. But I got my app working by using gem sprocket-rails. I am trying to upgrade an app from Rails 6 to 7 while moving it from Heroku to Fly.io. I  think I've settled on sprocket-rails (esbuild) and jsbundling-rails for the time being as Rails makes major changes with the asset pipeline. I looked at importmaps. Quit using Webpacker, but not webpack. I don't want my app to fall to far behind, but propshaft is too far ahead for now. I think DHH says that will be the standard in Rails 8. And of course this is all mixed in with Hotwire transition.